# Input circuit for ESP8266

Tags: microcontroller, esp8266, input

I built the following simple circuit as an input to an ESP8266 microcontroller:

[image]

When I hold the switch closed, the input goes low. How do I modify this circuit to do the opposite? I want to press a switch to produce a high signal for the input to the microcontroller.

Comment: if you use INPUT_PULLUP, you only need the switch+ground+GPIO: no resistor or vcc

Comment: @dandavis Thanks. Can you write that up as an answer?

Comment: it doesn't answer the question asked as well as the given one, but glad to help.

Comment: @dandavis It still answers the question that I didn't even know to ask.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX9Myc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Of course! I need some resistance on the ground circuit to force  the current from the source to go to the I/O connection. Thanks!

Comment: It would be better to change the GPIO to pull-down as well.